# How to import local package in typescript monorepo

Tags: typescript, npm

Given a monorepo project.

`--project_root/
  |--packageA/
     |--index.ts
     |--package.json
     |--foo/
        |--index.ts
  |--packageB/
     |--index.ts
     |--package.json
     |--bar/
        |--spam.ts`

Normally, when you are in `packageA/index.ts` and you want to import `packageB/index.ts` you would do `import index from '../packageB'`,

and when you are `packageA/foo/index.ts` and you want to import `packageB/index.ts` you need to move two directory up `import index from '../../packageB'`

The question is, is there a way to import like `import index from 'packageB` and for nested folder `import spam from 'packageB/bar/spam'`?

**EDIT**

I have uploaded a github repo to demo the issue
https://github.com/jaimesangcap/lerna-ts-monorepo

Comment: You should use Project References. See [the second half of this answer, under "this is great for monorepos"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61467483/8910547)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can do this by specifing the [base url](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#base-url) and (in more complicated cases) by using [path mapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#path-mapping).

If you have a `tsconfig.json` in `project_root`, you can achieve the desired import strategy by defining

```
"compilerOptions": {
  "baseUrl": "."
}
```

This works if the package name always corresponds with the folder name of the sub-project.

If this isn't the case, you can use `paths`:

```
"compilerOptions": {
  "baseUrl": ".", // This must be specified if "paths" is.
  "paths": {
    "A": ["packageA"],
    "B": ["packageB"],
    "A/*": ["packageA/*"],
    "B/*": ["packageB/*"]
  }
}
```

This will cause typescript to correctly resolve the types of import during compilation. However the import paths are not resolved in the compiled javascript, which means it is necessary to tell the next step in your pipeline (usually a bundler like webpack) how to resolve these imports as well. For webpack specifically this can by done by specifying an [alias](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve-alias) in the webpack config:

```
resolve: {
  alias: {
      A: path.resolve(__dirname, 'packageA/'),
      B: path.resolve(__dirname, 'packageB/')
  }
}
```

If you want to execute the typescript files directly, [ts-node](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node) is the easiest way to do so, since it will already know about the modified paths from the typescript config if you use [tsconfig-paths](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node#loading-tsconfigjson) - in this case you just have to execute the file using `ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register packageA/index.ts` (`ts-node` and `tsconfig-paths` have to be installed via npm)

Comment: thank you provding example but it doesn't seem to work out of the box (without a bundler). the package path is not transformed into the relative path of the package. 
See article https://medium.com/@caludio/how-to-use-module-path-aliases-in-visual-studio-typescript-and-javascript-e7851df8eeaa

Comment: I'm still trying to follow along the examples of the article though.

Comment: Could you specify how you try to run your javascript files? If you are using webpack, you can [specify the same resolutions there](https://github.com/s-panferov/awesome-typescript-loader/issues/311#issuecomment-270222049), if you are running the js files directly via `node`, you can use [npm link](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link). If you update your question, I will update my answer

Comment: Depending on your situation it is also possible to use [local paths](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#local-paths). Maybe linking the individual projects is sufficient four your usecase and you don't even need configuration on typescript level

Comment: Hi Johannes, I will create a github repo and post it here. I would appreciate if you can have a look at it thank you.

Comment: I made an edit to provide the link for the github repo

Comment: Hey, you already solved it yourself using ts-node and tsconfig-paths, very nice :) I updated the answer accordingly

Comment: yup :) thank you for providing the examples! accepting as answer as it covers the common cases with or without the bundler.

Comment: btw, would you mind sharing your insight about this issue related to typescript monorepo? https://github.com/dividab/tsconfig-paths/issues/65