# How can I modify components within a node_modules folder on the fly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, yalc

I have two repos.

1. a component library
2. an app called Component Playground, which allows users to visualise/interact with all of the components within the library before we use them on other apps within the same monorepo.

While building my app, I want to be able to modify the components from within the repo 2), so I can see how they behave instantly, rather than making modifications in repo 1) then having to push to GitHub etc.

I've tried yarn link, npm link and yalc. None of them seem to be able to do what I'm asking. Does anyone have any insight into how I might be able to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to import local package in typescript monorepo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53399474/how-to-import-local-package-in-typescript-monorepo)

Comment: I'm using [pnpm workspaces](https://pnpm.io/workspaces). Here's a [short youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ngdoUQBvAjo). He also uses `nx` as a later step, but that is optional.